# Programmatic windows maximization

Tags: gnome

I learned about wmctrl here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103602/how-to-maximize-a-window-programmably-in-x-window which suggests using the following command to programmatically maximize a windows:

```
wmctrl -i -r (windows ID) -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

but for some reason it is not working.  I'm working in Ubuntu 14.04LTS.  Does anybody out there knows why?  Does anybody know about an alternative?

EDIT: I restarted and now it is working! But unfortunately I don't know whether I made some mistake before or restarting is really necessary.

Comment: The command works perfectly here, both Unity *and* Gnome. What is the full command you run, and (sorry for asking) is `wmctrl` installed? (Not by default).

Comment: yes I installed it and the command wmctrl -l from which I get the windows ID is working.  The command I am using is exactly the one you see in the question with the windows ID substituted with the one I read from wmctrl -l. I'll put a screenshot in a moment.

Comment: Normally, restarting is not necessary, so I have the feeling you made a mistake :) BTW, an alternative would be `xdotool`'s `xdotool windowsize <window_id> 100% 100%` -command, but you won't need it I guess :)

Comment: I can't find a "useful comment" button for you here. So I can only say thanks. I would accept your comment as answer.

Comment: No, go ahead..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your command on both Unity and Gnome, and it works fine in both cases. So there is a chance you made a mistake in the command.

*If* you would want an alternative solution, you could use `xdotool`'s command:

```
xdotool windowsize <window_id> 100% 100%
```

You would however need to install xdotool:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```